# About React-Native index.js

Tags: react-native

This day I study React Native, but one problem is too hard

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

```
error: index.js: Unknown option: .plugs. Check out https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-core/#options for more information about options.
```

this is my script index.js

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from '~/App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `import App from '~/App';` with `import App from './App';`

Comment: First thank you for comment!
Is not work...
I use type script and babel plugin